# How to call API using Retrofit in Android

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit, retrofit2

Link : https://mobileinterview.azurewebsites.net/api/products?PageIndex=1&PageSize=10

I am trying to call this API using retrofit in android using java but it does not return any response body it shows the response message is OK and the response code is 200, but still body is null.

Below is my code :

```
    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constant.BaseUrl)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .build();

    MyApiService services = retrofit.create(MyApiService.class);

    Call<JSONArray> call = services.getAllData();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONArray> call, Response<JSONArray> response) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: "+response);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONArray> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Below is my interface class :

```
@GET("products?PageIndex=1&PageSize=10")
Call<JSONArray> getAllData();
```

Comment: This example give you more details how use Retrofit : https://www.journaldev.com/13639/retrofit-android-example-tutorial

Comment: You have an XML API try not to save it in JSONArray or JSONObject. Or if possible use JSON generating API for the purpose

Comment: Here is a link that might help you https://medium.com/android-news/working-with-xml-using-retrofit2-21c3af9a0472

Answer (score 0):

your api data is xml based , you follow this topic for parsing the xml data , hopefully it will help your problem

https://codeleague.redquark.org/2018/08/parsing-xml-using-retrofit.html